# How I can resolve 502 (Bad Gateway) in API Platform custom operation?

Tags: symfony, nginx, docker-compose, api-platform.com

I faced up with the issue that seems to be NGINX issue. So, I created the API platform custom operation and when I request the route I see the following output:

`7#7: *9 upstream prematurely closed FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.31.0.1, server: , request: "GET /i18/device_help_tips HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.31.0.3:9000", host: "localhost:8080"`

My API Platform **config** is the following:

```
App\Api\Entity\DeviceHelpTip:
  properties:
  attributes:
    order:
      sorting: 'DESC'
  collectionOperations:
    get_i18:
      method: 'GET'
      path: '/i18/device_help_tips'
      controller: 'App\Api\Controller\DeviceHelpTip\PerformI18Request'
      security: "is_granted('ROLE_CONTENT_MANAGER') or is_granted('ROLE_MOBILE') or is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"
```

**Interesting fact:** if I remove in the security section one of the roles it will work correctly. Also I have the bearer auth here. If I try the request data with token - it will work fine, if no token - error mentioned above

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Api\Controller\DeviceHelpTip;

use App\Api\Handler\DeviceHelpTipI18RequestHandler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class PerformI18Request
{ 
    private DeviceHelpTipI18RequestHandler $deviceHelpTipI18RequestHandler;

    public function __construct(DeviceHelpTipI18RequestHandler $deviceHelpTipI18RequestHandler)
    {
        $this->deviceHelpTipI18RequestHandler = $deviceHelpTipI18RequestHandler;
    }

    public function __invoke($data)
    {
        $this->deviceHelpTipI18RequestHandler->handle($data);
    }
}
```

**NGINX** config:

```
server {
root /srv/api/public;
client_max_body_size 10M;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
    # Comment the next line and uncomment the next to enable dynamic resolution (incompatible with Kubernetes)
    fastcgi_pass api-backend:9000;
    #resolver 127.0.0.11;
    #set $upstream_host api-backend;
    #fastcgi_pass $upstream_host:9000;

    # Bigger buffer size to handle cache invalidation headers expansion
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
    # current version of your application, you should pass the real
    # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
    # FPM.
    # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
    # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
    # for more information).
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
    # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
    # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
    internal;
}

# return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
# this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
location ~ \.php$ {
  return 404;
}
}
```

I tried to change the **fastcgi_buffer_size** and **fastcgi_buffers** but with no result. If you need additional config please let me know in comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It started to throw this error for me, too. First on one route, after clean db and new migrate on another route. looked for hours but can´t find anything. Worked for almost a year.

Comment: Just to leave this note here: Facing the exact same problem as @develth.